# Virtual Box "system is not currently set up to build kernel modules" on 16.04 (xenial)

Tags: apt, 16.04, kernel, virtualbox, aptitude

I tried installing virtual box but I get the following error.

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig 
[sudo] password for dude: 
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  apt-get install linux-headers-generic
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  apt-get install linux-headers-generic

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

My current kernel is:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-24-generic
```

Trying to upgrade headers give me the following.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.21.22).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Tried to install linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic directly from deb still getting errors. From apt-get I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic' has no installation candidate
```

Surely there must be a way to fix this. Any suggestions? Help!

Comment: what does `apt-cache policy linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic` output?

Comment: linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: OK, `Candidate: none` is an important clue.  This is saying that it does not know where to get the package from.  Something is wrong with the way the repos are set up on your system.

Comment: On my system the package is found in `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main`it appears your system is not accessing this.  To check, what is the output of `apt-cache policy | grep updates`?

Comment: I don't get any output..

dude@dude:~$ apt-cache policy | grep updates
dude@dude:~$

Comment: I added the repo link you provided to my sources list and I am finally able to install it! Thanks a bunch. One question, how were you able to find the right link for the linux headers?

Comment: All the repos were set up properly on my system at install.  I'll write this as an answer, if it helped you, please accept.  I'll add more detail about the repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic` that you provided was an important clue to the root cause of this problem.  Since the command reported (in part) `Candidate: none` it was clear that the repos were not set up properly on your system, and therefore it didn't know where to find the desired package.  Add `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main` to your sources list and you should be able to install the package.

Just so you can check the rest of your sources list, here is what mine looks like, to use as an example (I removed the commented out lines).

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```